# RecognizerIntent not respecting language

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to make RecognizerIntent respect a custom language I'm setting it to listen to, but it just doesn't work. It looks like it just doesn't use the parameters I'm sending, respecting only system settings (if I change system's Voice Search settings, it does work).

This is how I'm creating the Intent:

```
val spanish = Locale("es", "ES").toString()
val recognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true)
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, spanish)
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, spanish)
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, spanish)
recognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", arrayOf(spanish))

startActivityForResult(recognizerIntent, REQUEST_SPEECH)
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Some of those extras are not applicable [to `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH). Are you sure that `Locale("es", "ES").toString()` turns into `es` or `es-ES`?

Comment: Well, I've just tested spanish = "es", spanish = "es-ES" and spanish = Locale("es", "ES") (without toString) but none worked.

Comment: It's also worth commenting that I've already done this to Android phones and it works:
recognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        recognizerIntent!!.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", arrayOf("en"))
        
        recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.US)
        recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (sharedPreferences.getAppLanguage() == LANGUAGE_ENGLISH) {
            recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        } else {
            recognizerIntent!!.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ar-AE")
        }
```